# How to pause and resume a thread in Java game development

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I need to know how to pause a thread and resume it after checking a condition.

```
  Thread t = new Thread () {
  public void run() { 
    while(true) {
      update();
      repaint();
      try {  
        Thread.sleep(50);
      } catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
  }


       };
```

The above code is my game loop and I need this to be pause and resumed if any condition is checked.

I think the thread can be started only once, so we cannot use `suspend()` nor `resume()`as it is deprecated.

```
// all imports goes here /** Bouncing Ball (Animation) via custom thread */

public class JavaApplication12 extends JFrame implements KeyListener{ 
    // Define named-constants
    private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 640;
    private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10;
    milliseconds int xx = 200; int yy = 500;
    Shape a1; Shape a2; float das[] = {10.0f}; int f = 20;

    boolean r = true;

    Font font = new Font("Arial",Font.ROMAN_BASELINE,f);

    BasicStroke color = new BasicStroke (10,BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL,10.0f,das,0.0f);
    GradientPaint dash = new GradientPaint(0,0,Color.BLUE,100,0,Col or.CYAN);

    Rectangle2D a3;

    Rectangle2D a12;
    Rectangle2D a4;
    Rectangle2D a5;
    Rectangle2D a6;
    Rectangle2D a7;
    Rectangle2D a8;
    Rectangle2D a9;
    Rectangle2D a10;
    Rectangle2D a11; Rectangle2D a13;
    Rectangle2D a14;
    Rectangle2D a15; Rectangle2D a16;
    Rectangle2D a17; Rectangle2D a18;
    Rectangle2D a19; Rectangle2D a20;
    Rectangle2D a21; Rectangle2D a22;
    Rectangle2D a23;
    Rectangle2D a25;

    ArrayList s = new ArrayList();

    Color c2 = Color.RED;

    private DrawCanvas canvas; //the drawing canvas (extends JPanel)

    // Attributes of moving object
    // top-left (x, y)
    private int x = 200;
    private int y = 480;
    //width and height
    private int size = 20;
    //moving speed in x and y directions
    private int xSpeed = 3;
    //displacement per step in x and y
    private int ySpeed = 5; 

    /** Constructor to setup the GUI components */
    public JavaApplication12() {
        canvas = new DrawCanvas();

        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));

        this.setContentPane(canvas);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_ CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setTitle("Bouncing Ball");
        this.setVisible(true); addKeyListener(this);

        fun();

    }

    Thread updateThread = new Thread() { @Override public void run() {

        while (r) { update(); // update the (x, y) position

            repaint(); // Refresh the JFrame. Called back paintComponent()

            try { // Delay and give other thread a chance to run

                Thread.sleep(UPDATE_INTERVAL); //milliseconds

            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {} } }

    };

    /** Update the (x, y) position of the moving object */
    public void update() { 
        x += xSpeed; y += ySpeed; 
        if (x > CANVAS_WIDTH - size || x < 0) { xSpeed = -xSpeed; } 
        if (y > CANVAS_HEIGHT - 80 || y < 0) { ySpeed = -ySpeed;  }

    }

@Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) { }

@Override

@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "deprecation"}) 
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) { 
    int keycode = ke.getKeyCode(); 
    if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) { xx = xx-15; } 
    if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) { 
        if(r == true) { 
            //r = false;
            updateThread.start();
        }

    } 
    if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {    }

    if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) { xx = xx+15; }

}

@Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) { 
    // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

/** DrawCanvas (inner class) is a JPanel used for custom drawing */
    class DrawCanvas extends JPanel { 
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
        int i=0; 
        int liv = 3;

        @Override

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); //paint parent's background Graphics2D d = (Graphics2D)g;

            a1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,size,size);
            d.drawLine(0,540,640,540);
            for(Rectangle2D r : s){ 
                    d.setStroke(color);
                    //d.setPaint(dash);
                    d.draw(r); 
            }
            a25 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,540,1000,10);
            d.draw(a25);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                d.setColor(Color.BLUE);

                a2 = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(xx,yy,120,10,2 0,20);

                d.fill(a1); d.setPaint(c2);
                d.fill(a2); d.setFont(font);
                d.drawString("Score : "+i,5,575);
                d.drawString("Life : "+liv,550,575);

                if(a1.intersects(a25.getBounds())) {
                    if(liv>0) { liv = liv-1;}

                    if(liv == 0) { //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "","",0);

                    } }

                if(s.contains(a3) && a1.intersects(a3.getBounds())) { 
                    i = i+10; s.remove(a3);
                    ySpeed = -ySpeed;
                    try { m(); } 
                    catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } } if(s.contains(a4) && a1.intersects(a4.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a4);ySpeed = -ySpeed;

                    try { m();

                    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } } if(s.contains(a5) && a1.intersects(a5.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a5);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } } if(s.contains(a6) && a1.intersects(a6.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a6);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } } if(s.contains(a7) && a1.intersects(a7.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a7);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } } if(s.contains(a8) && a1.intersects(a8.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a8);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); }

                } if(s.contains(a9) && a1.intersects(a9.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a9);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } } if(s.contains(a10) && a1.intersects(a10.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a10);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } } if(s.contains(a11) && a1.intersects(a11.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a11);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } } if(s.contains(a12) && a1.intersects(a12.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a12);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } } if(s.contains(a13) && a1.intersects(a13.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a13);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } } if(s.contains(a14) && a1.intersects(a14.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a14);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } } if(s.contains(a15) && a1.intersects(a15.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a15);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } }

                if(s.contains(a16) && a1.intersects(a16.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a16);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } }

                if(s.contains(a17) && a1.intersects(a17.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a17);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } }

                if(s.contains(a18) && a1.intersects(a18.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a18);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } }

                if(s.contains(a19) && a1.intersects(a19.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a19);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } }

                if(s.contains(a20) && a1.intersects(a20.getBounds())) { i = i+10; s.remove(a20);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } }

                if(s.contains(a21) &&a1.intersects(a21)) { i = i+10; s.remove(a21);ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } }

                if(s.contains(a22) && a1.intersects(a22)) { i = i+10; s.remove(a22); ySpeed = -ySpeed; try { m(); } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication12.cla ss.getName()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex); } }

                collide(); } public void m() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException { String a = "chimes.wav"; AudioInputStream aa = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File (a).getAbsoluteFile()); Clip c = AudioSystem.getClip(); c.open(aa); c.start(); }

    }

    public final void fun() { 
        a3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,15,100,20);
        a4 = new Rectangle2D.Double(150,15,100,20);
        a5 = new Rectangle2D.Double(280,15,100,20);

        a6 = new Rectangle2D.Double(400,15,100,20);
        a7 = new Rectangle2D.Double(530,15,100,20);

        a8 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,50,100,20);
        a9 = new Rectangle2D.Double(150,50,100,20);
        a10 = new Rectangle2D.Double(280,50,100,20);
        a12 = new Rectangle2D.Double(400,50,100,20);
        a11 = new Rectangle2D.Double(530,50,100,20);

        a13 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,85,100,20);
        a14 = new Rectangle2D.Double(150,85,100,20);
        a15 = new Rectangle2D.Double(280,85,100,20);
        a16 = new Rectangle2D.Double(400,85,100,20);
        a17 = new Rectangle2D.Double(530,85,100,20);

        a18 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,120,100,20);
        a19 = new Rectangle2D.Double(150,120,100,20);
        a20 = new Rectangle2D.Double(280,120,100,20);
        a21 = new Rectangle2D.Double(400,120,100,20);
        a22 = new Rectangle2D.Double(530,120,100,20);

        s.add(a3); s.add(a4); s.add(a5); s.add(a6);
        s.add(a7); s.add(a8); s.add(a9); s.add(a10);
        s.add(a11); s.add(a12);
        s.add(a13); s.add(a14); s.add(a15); s.add(a16);
        s.add(a17); s.add(a18);
        s.add(a19); s.add(a20); s.add(a21); s.add(a22); }

    public void collide() {

        if(a2.intersects(a1.getBounds())) {

            xSpeed = xSpeed; ySpeed = -ySpeed;

        } }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // Run GUI codes in Event-Dispatching thread for thread safety 
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
            @Override public void run() { 
                new JavaApplication12(); // Let the constructor do the job
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to pause from within that thread itself or from some other thread?

Comment: You need to give us more information about your scenario. Give us a condition variable to work with. Declare variables in your code, indicate the position where you want to do condition checking and pausing.

Comment: I have my code here but nit aligned plz manage as I'm using net from phone

Comment: When the user presses the escape key the game should pause again if press the same key it should continue.

Comment: I was gone out with my wife, I've attempted an answer. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: terrible source code. Can't you make up something small and meaningful, and properly indented? I tried to fix your source code and haven't even fixed half of it after 3 minutes

Comment: Are you sure you really wanna do multi-threading? Please consider using a [Swing `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for triggering your updates. This works without the need to think about the odds of multi-threading and the `Timer` has `start` and `stop` methods…

Comment: Will u Please tell me how to implemeny timers for game development? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah! Went through the `timer` and it is so easy. Got want I wanted thanks @Holger

Comment: @user3705482 Your question looks really ugly, you need to work on formatting it in a big way. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

In addition to  `sleep()`, `Thread` has two other static methods called `wait()` and `await()` that are specifically for this purpose.

If you want an instance of class `Foo` to pause and wait for an instance of class `Bar` to tell it to wake up:

```
//in Foo class
synchronized void doStuffAndWait() throws InterruptedException {
    //do stuff
    while(!someCondition) { 
           wait();
           System.out.println("I woke up!");
    }

//in Bar class; 
synchronized void wakeFooUp(Foo foo){
    foo.someCondition = true; 
    foo.notify();
}
```

when your foo instance gets done doing stuff and `someCondition` evaluates to false, it enters the while loop. The while loop throws some people off, because what happens isn't really "iterative" in the traditional sense.

To illustrate: If you put a call to  `Thread.sleep(1000)` inside a loop, there would be a 1-second pause between each iteration of it. In the same sense, assuming `someCondition` evaluates to false, the thread is put to sleep in the first iteration of that loop. But rather than going to sleep for a fixed amount of time, it goes to sleep indefinitely - until something else calls `notify()` on it. When it wakes up, it simply goes on to the next line after `wait()` (just like it does when a call to `sleep()` completes). In this case,it prints "I woke up" and then checks someCondition again. Had your `Bar` not set that condition to true before notifying it, it would have gone back to sleep.

I should note that this has been a very simplistic introductory explanation, and that what we're talking about - which is  called [concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) - is a notoriously complex topic.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AtomicBoolean` object as a lock that you can wait on.

The following code should flip the `AtomicBoolean` `is_running` every time escape key is pressed.(we flip it on the line `is_running.set(!is_running.get());`...) When it flips from `true` to `false`, the next iteration of `while(r)` in the `updateThread` will `wait` inside the `synchronized` block. It'll be woken up the next time `notify_all` method is called on the `is_running` object.(which will happen the next time escape key is pressed). So when the Escape key is pressed again, the `is_running` flag is flipped again, and the `notify_all` method call will wake-up the `updateThread`, at which point the `continue` statement will take it to the top of the while loop and after checking the `is_running` to make sure that the flag is true, it will go and execute the `update()` and `repaint()` code and keep looping until the flag is flipped again.

I've obviously not tested this code, please let me know if there are errors in the code.

```
JavaApplication12 extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
...
AtomicBoolean is_running(true);
...
Thread updateThread = new Thread() {
  @Override public void run() {
    while (r) {
      synchronized(is_running) {
        if(!is_running.get()) {
          is_running.wait();
          continue;
        }
      }
      update(); // update the (x, y) position
      repaint(); // Refresh the JFrame. Called back paintComponent()
      try { // Delay and give other thread a chance to run
        Thread.sleep(UPDATE_INTERVAL); //milliseconds
      } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
    }
  }
};
...
@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "deprecation"}) public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
  ...
  } if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
    synchronized(is_running)
      is_running.set(!is_running.get());
      is_running.notify_all();
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: No brother it does not work,after adding the code thr `thread` is not at all starts.how will that flip from `true` to `false` I don't get this logic.

Comment: @user3705482 I forgot to initialize `is_running` like `AtomicBoolean is_running(true);` I've fixed that in the code. Does it work now? `is_running` is flipped by the line `is_running.set(!is_running.get());`